# vb.net building string with null values

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to build an address string like this:

```
Dim billingAddress As String() = {dr("BillingFirstName") & " " & dr("BillingLastName"), StrConv(dr("BillingAddress1"), VbStrConv.ProperCase), StrConv(dr("BillingAddress2"), VbStrConv.ProperCase), StrConv(dr("BillingCity"), VbStrConv.ProperCase), StrConv(dr("BillingCounty"), VbStrConv.Uppercase), StrConv(dr("BillingCountry"), VbStrConv.ProperCase), StrConv(dr("BillingPostcode"), VbStrConv.Uppercase)}
```

When a value from the database is null i get an error.  Can anyone tell me the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the ToString() function on your Data Reader:

```
dr("BillingFirstName").ToString & " " & etc...
```

If it's null, it will turn it into an empty string.